# Apache - where do I get older access logs? Are they even there?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

As the question says, I can find access logs upto 1 month old in the /var/logs/httpd folder. Where do I get older access logs from?

Are they even maintained/saved anywhere or deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your logrotate settings for those particular logs. You'll see the time interval for it to start a new log and how many copies it must keep. Anything prior to that gets deleted, so you would need to restore them from your backups.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I see these? I don't see a rotate or a logrotate in my httpd.conf

Comment: @lostInTransit, logrotate is not part of Apache, it's a system utility, so you'll find its settings in /etc and/or a sub-directory of /etc. On my Debian system what you're looking for is in /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.

Answer (score 3):

Usually they are deleted.

It all depends on the specific distribution you're using, but most use `logrotate` to compress and delete old log files. This configuration should be in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and individual files in `/etc/logrotate.d`